# Javascript error & GET request failure from Google custom search

Tags: javascript, css, google-custom-search

I've encountered an issue with a custom Google search engine I've integrated into my site. I have some other Google elements on the same page, such as the +1 button and G+ badge, but I've isolated and verified that the search element is, in fact, the culprit.

The problem is the following: the GET request for http://www.google.com/uds/api/ads/3.0/9f53ed6be164615d919d9e4bd4f7fe8d/search.I.js seems to fail (although searching the site still works). The dev console in Chrome says that the request is initiated by their jsapi on line 21 and has the following highlighted in red:

```
google.(anonymous function).d
  (anonymous function)
```

I've tried multiple test scenarios, including inserting the search box on a completely barebones HTML page, but I get the same error. What is causing the request to fail? Is it simply something on their end (and thus unfixable)?

Edit: Relevant code

This is all taken verbatim from Google's code generators.

This goes right before `</head>`

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '004344714102800561193:mo5u_njahwy';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
```

The search box code:

```
<gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

Search results page code:

```
<gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Comment: It's hard to say. Do you have a link or something for us to take a look at?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yup, edited to include relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an ad blocker installed like Adblock Plus? I'm getting this error when I run your code in JSFiddle:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

It looks like that error is often caused by an ad blocker preventing the file from being loaded: [Meta - What are these errors about in the Chrome console when visiting StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223764/what-are-these-errors-about-in-the-chrome-console-when-visiting-stackoverflow)